# Core Data, UITableView, and UISegmentedControl

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-data

I am new to working with Core Data, and am working with a UITableView.  I have a toolbar with a UISegmentedController, and I want to filter the items in the UITableView based on the selected index.  In other words, suppose I have a UITableView that displays Books (stored in Core Data) and a UISegmentedController with segments to display books in "English", "Spanish", and "French".

What is the approach here to get everything hooked up?  When one of the segments is clicked, what do I do in the UISegmentedControl's target to change things around?

Sorry if it's a stupid question!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would use a *separate* `NSFetchedResultsController` for each segment.  This will allow you to take advantage of the built in cache for each segment and improve performance.

In addition to Apple's documentation (and my book), you can also read up on them from my article [Touching The Core](http://pragprog.com/magazines/2010-01/touching-the-core) in the PragPub magazine.

Comment: I can't help but say that as you someone that already gives so much to the community, I am absolutely astonished that you take the time to answer questions like mine on SO.  A million thank you's!

Comment: Marcus, what would be the cleanest way to implement this? If you had three segments, this would require three FRC's, and it wouldn't be very pretty to have all those `switch() case:` statements in the tableview code. Perhaps create a `typedef enum` with labels corresponding to the individual segments then add the FRC's to an NSArray in the class at the appropriate indices? Then all you would have to do is reference something like `[self.frcArray objectAtIndex:[segControl selectedSegmentIndex]]` where there would otherwise be a `switch() case`. Or is there a cleaner way to do it?

Comment: have them as iVars and have a `currentFRC` iVar.  When the segmented control is tapped, you switch what `currentFRC` is pointing to and tell the tableView to reload.  Everything else talks to the `currentFRC` and have checks in your delegate methods so they ignore any messages that are not from the `currentFRC`.

Answer (score 0):

Its a good idea to use three different Arrays for each of your filters. Cache them somewhere so their is no delay when the user selects a filter. To find the information you are looking for from your CoreData store use NSPredicate.

Comment: Using arrays with Core Data is more code than you need to write.  Better to use a `NSFetchedResultsController` as that is what it is designed for.

Comment: duly noted: I especially like that NSFetchedResultsController uses some kind of caching. Most of my data is dynamic so I guess I think in NSMutableArrays for most things

Comment: Even with dynamic data, Core Data with an In-Memory store plus a `NSFetchedResultsController` is going to be less code and better performance in nearly every situation.  Food for thought.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `NSFetchedResultsController`, when you clicked on segment just set the different perdicate and perform fetch again.

Comment: Read: http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/CoreData/Reference/NSFetchedResultsController_Class/Reference/Reference.html for creating and using NSFetchedResultsController.

Comment: If you only use one then you lose the advantage of its cache.  Better to use one for each segment.

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented this as follows using the guidelines from Marcus above(I'm new to this so it may not be the best approach). I have a segment controller with three options for 'open', 'in progress' and 'closed'.

In the ViewController.h, create an iVar for each one of your segment options, and one iVar for the main controller that will store the current controller.

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSFetchedResultsController *fetchedResultsController;

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSFetchedResultsController *inprogressFetchedResultsController;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSFetchedResultsController *openFetchedResultsController;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSFetchedResultsController *closedFetchedResultsController;
```

In the ViewController.m you need to create methods for lazy loading of these controllers, so I have three in total. They are basically the same except for the predicate and the cacheName, I have only shown one below.

```
- (NSFetchedResultsController *)closedFetchedResultsController
{
    if (_closedFetchedResultsController != nil) {
        return _closedFetchedResultsController;
    }

    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];

    // Edit the entity name as appropriate.
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Ticket" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

    // Set the batch size to a suitable number.
    [fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:20];

    // Edit the sort key as appropriate.
    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"priority.name" ascending:NO];
    NSArray *sortDescriptors = @[sortDescriptor];

    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"status = 'Closed'"];
    [fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];

    NSFetchedResultsController *aFetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:@"priority.name" cacheName:@"ClosedTickets"];
    aFetchedResultsController.delegate = self;

    self.closedFetchedResultsController = aFetchedResultsController;

    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![self.closedFetchedResultsController performFetch:&error]) {
        // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
        // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        abort();
    }

    return _closedFetchedResultsController;
}
```

Create an IBAction for your segment so that when it is changed it changes the fetched results controller and reloads the table.

```
- (IBAction)statusChanged:(id)sender {
    switch (self.segmentControl.selectedSegmentIndex) {
        case 0:
            self.fetchedResultsController = self.inprogressFetchedResultsController;
            break;
        case 1:
            self.fetchedResultsController = self.openFetchedResultsController;
            break;
        case 2:
            self.fetchedResultsController = self.closedFetchedResultsController;
            break;
        default:
            break;

    }
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

That's it!

N.B. I also added this line to my ViewDidLoad method so that it would load the correct option into the fetchedResultsController initially.

```
self.fetchedResultsController = self.inprogressFetchedResultsController;
```